# Change radio button input when click on the any point of the entire parent div

Tags: jquery, html, input, radio-button, checked

I am using radio input as a switch that alternates languages to be displayed on my website. The radio input has a class of ".switch", which is wrapped by its parent div ".switch-block". What I am trying to achieve is that when click on any point of the parent div(.switch-block, the coloured part on jsfiddle in the following), the input state will be changed, too.

My jquery code which is not working:

```
$('.switch-block').click(function(){
     $( ".switch" ).change();
});
```

Here's my attempt on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ev9s6h2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('.switch-block').click(function (e) {
     var $target = $(e.target);
     if (!($target.is(':radio'))) {
         $(this).find('input:radio:NOT(:checked)').prop('checked', true)
     }
 });
```

You can try this.

1. Attach the click event to the container.
2. Catch the target so that if the target is the radio then you just take the default action.
3. If the targeted element is not the radio then change the prop for the radio that is not checked to checked = true.

https://jsfiddle.net/usq5gb96/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.switch-block').click(function(){
     if($( ".switch" ).attr("checked"))
        $( ".switch" ).attr('checked', true);
     else
        $( ".switch" ).attr('checked', false);
});
```

Do something like this.

Comment: Do something like what? Explain what is going on!

Comment: If it was, why was this question asked?

Comment: If the radio button is checked then uncheck it and if it is not then check it. :)

Comment: So their is differnece between thinking the logic and coding it. The logic was already mentioned in the question, i didn't think it, i just coded :) @SterlingArcher

Comment: you shouldn't be re-selecting from the DOM every time. also, `this` is the DOM element inside of the handler, and `this.checked` will yield positive results ;)

Comment: `this.checked` won't work as the clicked element is not the radio button. Their can be many radio button so i couldn't convert the jQuery object to the DOM element for which i can use `.checked` directly. @rlemon

Comment: okay, my bad I didn't check his fiddle. The re-selecting from the DOM still stands tho.

Comment: @rlemon thats true :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your html this code works:

```
$('.switch-block').click(function(){
    $fr=$("#switch-fr");
    $en=$("#switch-en");
     if($en.is(":checked")) {
        $en.prop('checked', true);
     } else if($fr.is(":checked")) {
        $fr.prop('checked', true);
     }
   console.log($(this).find("input:radio:checked").val());
});
```

as you can see in the console.log it selects the right language choice
here a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ev9s6h2/2/)